# Java Swing Look and Feel Custom

Tags: java, swing

I know there are a lot of threads about this but I seriously couldn't find the answer. I looked at the oracle docs and read almost everything about the look and feel but I didn't read the part about how to create a custom look and feel with a XML file. The oracle docs said there was a way to create a custom look and feel programmatically and it said it was in the API documentation but I looked it up and could only find how to create a custom one with XML files.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html
Here is the link, it says you can create a custom look and feel programmatically in the last sentence of the 1st paragraph.

Now here is the question: Is there any way to programmatically create a look and feel? If not does java have some link to where there are all the possible options of look and feels? Also if there is any good video tutorial on look and feel as I really don't like to read the oracle docs (very boring) then please give a link. Thanks guys!

Comment: Ok apparently the only way to make a custom look and feel is the use of a xml file, the oracle docs has an error then because it literally said you could make a look and feel theme programatically without xml files.

Comment: You _can_ create the necessary classes for a new look and feel if you want. But this is a **huge** effort. If you want to know how to do it, look at the code of an open source look and feel implementations (e.g. JGoodiesLook)

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer!